# How to get an Integer from roman number via string variable in expl3?

Tags: expl3, programming, roman-numerals

Why when I try to use `\int_from_roman:n {\l_roman_str}` with `\l_roman_str` containing string (roman number), it does not work? As fo me, it's not obvious at all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\str_new:N \l_roman_str

\NewDocumentCommand{\RomanToInt}{ m }
{
    \str_set:Nn \l_roman_str {#1}
    \int_from_roman:n {\l_roman_str} % this one does not work
    %\int_from_roman:n {#1} % this one well done
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\RomanToInt{mmc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: We have a good answer, but remember the general principle: unless documented otherwise, `expl3` functions act on the input _as given_ not on the value or expansion of the input. (Ultimately TeX is a macro-expansion system.)

Comment: You have a series of very similar questions and in none of them setting a variable seems necessary for the result you want. I understand these are just examples, but perhaps more context will give better ideas on how to accomplish your purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\int_from_roman:n` does not convert the input `\l_roman_str` to its expansion but uses `l_roman_str` as literal value, which is 'nonsense' as input for that macro, leading to `-1` as output.

However, `\int_from_roman:V` does use the content of `\l_roman_str`, provided, the corresponding variant is given with `\cs_generate_variant:Nn`.

Now, there might be reasons why `\int_from_roman:n{#1}` is not used directly, but that's not clear at the moment, so defining the variant is one possibility to get around this issue when the string representation of the number is to be stored in a `\str` variable first...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\ior_new:N \g_file_ior
\str_new:N \l_roman_str

\cs_generate_variant:Nn \int_from_roman:n {V}

\NewDocumentCommand{\CharCount}{ m }
{
    \str_set:Nn \l_roman_str {#1}
    \int_from_roman:V \l_roman_str
    %\int_from_roman:n {#1} % this one well done
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\CharCount{mmc}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for your excellent work. Very nice. To my friends always upvote.

Comment: `\int_from_roman:n` internally does `\tl_to_str:n {#1}`.

Comment: It's also documented: »The roman numeral is first converted to a string, with no expansion.«

Comment: @HenriMenke: That' s basically what I wrote right from the start